# Worklight Eari show map using transition:'none'

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, esri, dojox.mobile

my code:

```
 <div id="homeView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
      <div id="loadmap" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" 
                data-dojo-props="label:'Load  Map  ', moveTo:'mapView', 
                transition:'slide'>
  </div>

  <div id="mapView" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
  </div>
```

This works.  the map displays

if I change transition to "none"   An error occurs "function graphics does not exists for object null"  The map doe not appear, everything else does; buttons, heading.

On the map page  I can click a button and another page is displayed.  On this page, I can click a button and see the map page with the map.  This transition used slide.

In short  changing views with transition: slide  to a view with a map works.
          changing views with transition: none   to a view with a map doe not work

Any ideas ?

Comment: What Dojo control are you using to display the map? I have seen you removed that part, so if this is specific to the Map control, that would be a relevant detail.

Comment: Try closing the double-quote (") for data-dojo-props. The listItem may be breaking because the data element isn't properly formed.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe looks similar to this Dojo bug: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15429 . However, this old bug used to hurt in Dojo 1.7, and is fixed starting with Dojo 1.8.0, while I assume (hope) you are using either 1.8.3 or 1.9.0. Please tell the result of alert("dojo.version: " + dojo.version), and also your Worklight version.

On the other side, your code excerpt has some syntax errors: the div of homeView is not closed, and the data-dojo-props of  data-dojo-props div misses a trailing ". I guess they are just typos when copying your code here. Fixing these errors and trying it out with Dojo 1.8.3, it still works fine for me after changing "slide" to "none".

Pasting as-is the complete error message that you get may help. Do you reproduce when running in a webbrowser? The stack trace of the error could be helpful too.